# UPDATE field with CASE statement match or do nothing to that field while still updating other fields in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get this UPDATE query to change my "offer_period" field (datetime) value to NOW() only if the offer_period field's value is greater than NOW(). The problem is, regardless of this field, I need to update my "status" field no matter what.

Because the status field must be updated, I cannot change the WHERE clause to include any offer_period condition or the status field won't get an update if that condition is not met.

With the below query, the ELSE statement is causing me problems. If I ommit it, the offer_period field value will be changed to NULL if the CASE condition is not met, which is bad because I want it to do nothing in these instances. So I tried including the ELSE condition that updates with the existing offer_period value, but the results then say 0 rows were affected. So this is where I'm stuck.

Thanks for taking the time.

Josh

```
UPDATE listings
SET `status`= 'Pending'
    , offer_period = CASE
                       WHEN offer_period > NOW() THEN NOW()
                       ELSE offer_period
                     END
WHERE listing_id=1
    AND agent_id=1
```

Comment: ELSE offer_period just keeps the current value ,thats why it say 0 rows affected.You want to update with what already exists??

Comment: No I don't, but when I ommit the ELSE part, it changes the offer_period value to NULL, which I don't want.

Comment: Ok,so what's the problem then?

Comment: What does `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM listings WHERE listing_id=1 AND agent_id=1 AND (status <> 'Pending' OR offer_period > NOW());` return?

Comment: And are you using MySQL or SQL-Server? Please correct the tags.

Comment: @Mihai: You're right, there is no problem. It works with the ELSE satement... now. I don't know, apparently its been a long day. Sorry guys. I was just forgetting to change the status column back to NULL after I changed it to Pending which once tested again is what was producing the 0 rows because nothing changed. I feel stupid. Perhaps I am :)

Comment: @JoshuaHutchison Eh,don`t worry,we all make mistakes.

Comment: @JoshuaHutchison Don't forget to close this Question, it's useless to let it in the unanswered list...